# How to call VSTEST.CONSOLE.EXE from batch file

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, vstest

I have unit test class library.

```
 ABC.dll
```

Now I have to execute it from `.bat` file:

```
 start %comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86
```

After that I have to add my dll ... with it
like

```
VSTEST.CONSOLE.EXE C:/ABC.dll /logger:trx
```

How can i achieve this? Please guide me kindly

Comment: Are you trying to execute the tests in the dll using `MsTest`?

Comment: remove the `start  %comspec% /k ` and put both lines in a batch file would seem like a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Call `vstest.console.exe` within your batch file, and pass the DLL as a command line argument.

Example .BAT:

```
start cmd /k ""%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" "C:/ABC.dll" /Logger:trx"
```

Note: Edit it, so the path to `vs.test.console.exe` is correct for whatever version of VS you have installed.